# Hibernate4: mappings in hibernate.cfg.xml not parsed

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working with Hibernate 4.3.6. 
The javadoc of `org.hibernate.cfgConfiguration` says:

```
This will be replaced by use of     
org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and    
org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources instead after the 4.0 release at
which point this class will become deprecated and scheduled for removal in 5.0.
```

So I tried to use `MetadataSources` and `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` to build my sessionFactory, here's my code:

```
package com.lithops.ims;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            MetadataSources md = new MetadataSources(srb.configure().build());
            return md.buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(new TradeHistory("123", new Date(), 1.2f, 100L));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

**TradeHistory.java**:

```
package com.lithops.ims.domain;
import java.util.Date;
public class TradeHistory {

    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private Date date;
    private float price;
    private long amount;
    public TradeHistory() {}
    public TradeHistory(String code, Date date, float price, long amount) {
        this.code = code;
        this.date = date;
        this.price =price;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    /* setters and getters omitted */
}
```

**TradeHistory.hbm.xml**(in the same package with `TradeHistory.java`):

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.lithops.ims.domain">
<class name="TradeHistory" table="TRADE_HISTORY">
    <id name="id" column="TRADE_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="code" column="STACK_CODE"/>
    <property name="date"  type="timestamp" column="TRADE_TIME"/>
    <property name="price" column="PRICE" />
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file(in `src/main/resources folder`) :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   
        <!-- properties omitted -->
        <mapping resource="com/lithops/ims/domain/TradeHistory.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But it seemed that the mappings in `hibernate.cfg.xml` were not parsed. When my application executed, `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity...` occurred.

The exception stack info :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.lithops.ims.domain.TradeHistory
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.lithops.ims.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:31)
```

**Note:** It worked well when using the `Configuration` class.

Comment: please post the code for `TradeHistory.hbm.xml` and `TradeHistory.java` file.

Comment: @ankur-singhal : missing files added. :)

Answer (score 0):

something like below

```
public void testConnection() throws Exception {

            logger.info("Trying to create a test connection with the database.");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate_sp.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            logger.info("Test connection with the database created successfuly.");
    }
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package your.package;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static
    {
        try
        {
//          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (HibernateException he)
        {
            System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    } 
}
```

**from blog**

need modify my hibernate 3.2.6 configuration and mapping files to use `xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"` and `xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping"` and also remove the dtd specifications.